# To add a white character between the leading word

Tags: oracle

For example

- (.aa) becomes (. aa)
- (..agsb) becomes (.. agsb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Albert's response, this method doesn't have the space problem:

```
select regexp_replace('..agsb', '^(\.+)([^. ])', '\1 \2') as output
from dual;
```

Comment: one problem sir if there is no trailing dot it is appending spaces for other dots also for example abc.cd becomes abc. cd ,it should remain abc.cd

Comment: @Sameersetia what are the valid conditions for adding spaces after dots? Is there a minimum/maximum number of valid dots? What can precede the dots? e.g. "add a space after two or up to four dots, whenever the dots are at the beginning of the line or after an open parenthesis". You need to be exact when you ask, in order to get an answer that fits your question :)

Comment: @Sameersetia no need to be, just state what you need and I'll update the query for you. For next time, you'll save time for yourself by asking questions that accurately match your needs ;)

Comment: Sorry for not providing complete information ,there can be only 2 trailing dots at the starting for example (..ab.c) should become (.. ab.c) and (. . ab.c)   remains the same

Comment: @Sameersetia at the starting of what? the whole string? text between brackets?

Comment: At the starting of whole string

Comment: @Sameersetia answer updated. You just need to use the anchor symbol (`^`) at the start of your regex to ensure it is only tested for the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp_replace for this requirement.

```
   select regexp_replace('..agsb',
              '(\.+)(.+)',
               '\1 \2') as output
 from dual;
```

Comment: what if there is already space between a dot  for example . aab it will become .  aab , how to stop this

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using wild-card matches for the start of the word, you can explicitly match the full-stop `\.` and word (either `[A-Za-z]` or, more permissively, `\w`) characters. Like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '..abc', '^(\.+)([A-Za-z])', '\1 \2' )
FROM   DUAL
```

If it can be other leading characters (rather than just full stops) then you can do:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '--abc', '^([^A-Za-z]*[^ A-Za-z])([A-Za-z])', '\1 \2' )
FROM   DUAL;
```